# How to use types as values in TypeScript? / Metatypes

Tags: javascript, swift, typescript, generics

I’m working on a component that fetches records from a data source. The component is written in TypeScript which I’m not super comfortable with.

Each record is characterized by a key and the record’s value type. The fetch method takes an instance of `RecordDescriptor<Value>` whose generic parameter `Value` determines the method’s return type.

In Swift, I would accomplish the goal with the following code, taking advantage of [*metatypes*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID455):

```swift
struct RecordDescriptor<Value> {
    let key: String
    let valueType: Value.Type // `Value.Type` is a metatype, the type of a type
}

func fetchValue<Value>(for descriptor: RecordDescriptor<Value>) -> Value {
    // …
}

let intRecordDescriptor = RecordDescriptor(key: "int_record", valueType: Int.self)
// `Int.self` refers to the `Int` type itself, not an instance of `Int`

let intValue = fetchValue(for: intRecordDescriptor)
```

Basically I get to specialize the generic parameter `Value` without using concrete instances of a type—only the type name itself.

**How do I achieve the same result in TypeScript?**

Comment: If I were you, I'd try to write this in JavaScript and post this as a JavaScript question because it has the biggest support base of any language in the world (whereas TypeScript is almost off the radar) and the conversion from JavaScript to TypeScript is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You don't care about `Metatypes` for their type-hinting capabilities, you only care about them for their ability to

> access initializers or other static members of the class or protocol

That's quite simply spelled as:

```js
interface Newable {
    new(): any
}

type Constructable<T> =
  T extends Newable
    ? T
    : T extends (...args: any[]) => unknown
      ? T : never

type RecordDescriptor<T, Key extends string> = { key: Key }
  & (
    T extends Constructable<T>
      ? { transformation: T }
      // Replace this arm with `never`
      // to not allow scalars / non-classes like `boolean`
      : { transformation: (arg?: unknown) => T }
    )
```

Usage is:

```js
let descriptorN: RecordDescriptor<Number, "numbers"> = {
  key: "numbers",
  transformation: Number
}
let resultN: Number = descriptorN.transformation("123")


let descriptorF: RecordDescriptor<(a: string, b: boolean) => string | boolean, "crazy"> =
  { key: "crazy", transformation: (a, b) =>  b ? "hi" : a.length > 3 }
let resultF: string | boolean = descriptorF.transformation("hmm", true)

let rp: RecordDescriptor<boolean, "options"> =
  { key: "options", transformation: () => true }
let resultP: boolean = rp.transformation()
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=43&pln=10&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIQO5wEYBsUDeAUMqciJgBQCUAXMnCAJ5EC+RRYTADigMIB7EAGcwUAK4IwOfAB4AKgD5kAXmTzkEAB6QQAE2FpMMlAH51yehu26DySgDoncKAHNh9RkwDaAXWqqyuIgANYgAhggyOYa9BQAbtAcXLzIAEoQCAJQegAiEMIIUMDcYNkKADTIANIQTJo6EPqGosUgrspqBMghdfS19azIAGT21o3NyIIiYpLSeBAKyubEZMhijMIw2QC2cGDAQlZslsjdGyLbUHsHR-Yurqb0wWERIAEqyhqs1Bz4YMg9AUiiUylBUPQMlkcvlCsVSuVUOIdthoFUAEQgZGoqDCdGdM49PrITHY6B4qoXLa7faHED0JEo6DIdj-ZBQAriXBgVCqQHA+Fg1AOKlXG50yjogCMACYAMzo35-CAAoFw0HZABikMy2TyAo1UFklDg9FaoFcVWw9GwAgE+EYH2U5vayAAPshbfaIIwMUU4AAvJj4vndXpMejo-1B9GUqCbMW0u4mq1O0jYaIkgAWwHRpzgDnw7TAWeQyjlLKIbI5wi5YG1yBdrndnrtDqiajVIIRUE1IvjlxptxAkqzOx2sfWEggSur3B10P16p7si97YxAlKdLxBLDxPRm+HFKnCaHdPoNECU-EKFZKvZnO5AAUbW2fR32dx+6frkmR9QgA)